# Is it possible to edit a post in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

When posting a new topic in Google Groups, I made a few misleading typos that I wanted to correct, but I couldn't find a way to edit the post. Is it possible to edit a post in Google Groups (in case I need to correct something in the post?)

Answer (score 15):

If you are the owner of the group then do the following:

You need to go to *Manage → Permission → Moderation permission*.
There change the *Edit other's post* and *Own Post*. Save.

If you are not the owner, ask the owner to enable edits by following the steps above.

Comment: Without the moderation permission looks like the only option we have is to delete the old post and re-create it..

Answer (score 7):

Once the message is posted it cannot be edited. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gmail-generation/7W51BDOBWIg

Latest Link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/panoramio-questions-support/SrK-xz4csCk

Comment: This message was posted in 2006 - has anything changed since then?

Comment: Also, I think I've found an exception to this limitation - it appears that it's possible to edit posts in the Chromebook Central group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/aSv3WovEigk

Comment: Here is the latest link.  has not changed this from begining. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/panoramio-questions-support/SrK-xz4csCk.  Interesting.. you are able to edit chromebook.. :)

Answer (score 1):

(Desktop in 2018) When viewing the post, in the upper right corner is a Reply button with a pull-down arrow for More Message Options.

Note: You'll see this option only if you are among the Select Groups Of Users allowed to Edit Others' Posts in Moderation Permissions (see a previous answer above for how to change that).

Pull down More Message Options and choose Edit.

You'll see a text link to Edit Subject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can I 've just done it. Go in your first text of the thread. click arrow on top right corner of the message: edit. there you can edit subject. and the whole thread subject changes!!. Must say I am owner and the one who started the thread.

Answer (score -2):

My experience in 2017 is that the only the person that wrote a Post can Edit it.

Comment: Dude, that's basic. Don't you think that other people shouldn't be able to edit your own posts?

Comment: No. Even if I'm the post creater, I cannot edit the post for some unknown reason. That's really embarrassing.